# How to intercept exception thrown from aspect in spring aop

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Is there any way to intercept exception and show meaningful message to end customer? I am trying to authorise my api using spring AOP and if end user is not authorised to access the API, I am throwing exception.

```
@Aspect
public class AuthorizationAspect {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(AuthenticateAccount)")
    public void authorized() {}

   private boolean isAuthorized() {
   // logic to check is user is authorised to call the api
   }

    @Before("authorized()")
    public void beforeControllerCall(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws UnauthorizedException {

        if(!isAuthorized)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("You don't have rights over this API");
        }

    }
}
```

By throwing the exception, I am able to prevent the acess to API, but it does not return me meaningful message which I am trying to throw in exception.

Has anyone worked with such use case and can help me with this?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or Spring Security?

Comment: I am using spring boot without spring security.

Comment: *Why* are you doing that? You almost certainly should use the extensive support for this that is already available, but if for some reason you're determined not to, `@ControllerAdvice` will handle all of what you need in an MVC-specific context.

Comment: I already tried RestControllerAdvice, but even it is unable to intercept those exceptions. May be RestControllerAdvice can intercept exceptions which are thrown from Controller, Service etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use global exception handling using `@ControllerAdvice`. Create your custom exception and throw that exception from Aspect class. You can create `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {UnauthorizedException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(UnauthorizedException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
      ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Please find spring boot global exception handling code below:

**DemoController.java**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    String hello(){
        return "Message from controller if there is no exception";
    }
}
```

**AuthException .java**

```
public class AuthException extends Exception{
    AuthException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

**AopValidator .java**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AopValidator {

    @Before("execution(String hello())")
     public void test() throws AuthException{
         throw new AuthException("Exception message from AOP on unauthorized access");
     }
}
```

**GlobalExceptionHandler.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthException.class)
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(AuthException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried @RestControllerAdvice, but no luck there.
Are you sure global exception handling will be able to intercept exception thrown from Aspect class?

Comment: Yes , I have used AOP for validation in my project . It work fine . If you are not able to solve issue . I would suggest you to add github link of your project in your post

Comment: Can `@Component` below your `@Aspect` and try again

Comment: Still not working. I cannot share the code or give github link. But I can assure you my RestControllerAdvice works well when any of my controller throws exception. But it does not work in this case.

Comment: So had to throw a exception which extends RuntimeException in order it to get intercepted by RestControllerAdvice. Seems like proxy instance throws **UndeclaredThrowableException** if checked exception is thrown from Aspect class. In case of unchecked exception, RestControllerAdvice is able to intercept it.

@Ajit Thanks for the guidance. May be you can update this in your answer and then I will accept it as working solution.

Comment: @amanraj I have added more code to my answer. I have created spring-boot application and tested my above code it works fine

Comment: It's weird that checked exception did not work in my case.